# A Puzzle of Row reduced Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is an excerpt from Fundamentals of Matrix Algebra by Gregory Hartman published by LibreTexts.

> A matrix is in *reduced row echelon form* if its entries satisfy the following conditions.
>
> 1. The first nonzero entry in each row is a $1$ (called a *leading $1$*).
> 2. Each leading $1$ comes in a column to the right of the leading $1$s in rows above it.
> 3. All rows of all $0$s come at the bottom of the matrix.
> 4. If a column contains a leading $1$, then all other entries in that column are $0$.
>
> A matrix that satisfies the first three conditions is said to be in *row echelon form*.

There are several questions which I came across when solving an exercise related to it :-

1. Does *row reduced echelon form* need to satisfy all the above $4$ conditions, or does it need only $1$ or $2$ of those conditions?
2. If it does need all the four conditions then how come $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ is in *row reduced echelon form*?

I don't have answer to the $1$st Question because according to the $2$nd Question the answer written in the book says **it is** in *row reduced echelon form*. But according to my logic it shouldn't be one because for a matrix to satisfy *row reduced echelon form* it needs to have *leading $1$* which is not present at all. Sow how come is that matrix in *row reduced echelon form*?

Let me take another example,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now this matrix doesn't have the last row of $0$s, but again this matrix is mention as a *row reduced echelon form* by the book.

Any ideas where I am understanding things wrong?

Comment: 1. Yes, all the conditions. 2. That's not what the definition says, reread it carefully. It says that any leading $1$s need to satisfy a certain condition. If there aren't any leading $1$s there's nothing to check. To be more precise it should read "*if* there is a leading $1$, then..." but this is usually left implicit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth for more background.

Comment: Hold on! I understood the 1st Question and also the point that if there is any leading 1 then only we need to have those first 2 and the fourth condition solved. But what about the last matrix? There isn't any rows of 0s but that is considered as row reduced echelon form.

Comment: It's the same thing: the condition is that "*if* there is a row of $0$s, then..." but for that last matrix there isn't one so there's nothing to check.

Comment: So that means it is by default in row reduced echelon form?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "by default." It satisfies all the conditions and the third one happens to be vacuous (maybe this is what you mean?). You really should click that Wikipedia link for more details.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. That clears the problem